# Why can't edit distance be solved as L1 distance?

Tags: shortest-path, edit-distance

Given two strings $x$ and $y$ over the alphabet $\Sigma$ one defines the edit-distance $\text{ed}(x,y)$ as the minimum number of substitutions, insertions and deletions of characters required to transform $x$ into $y$.

If $m = \max ( \text{len}(x),\text{len}(y) )$ then padding with appropriate zeroes on the smaller string one can define $x$ and $y$ as both being elements of $\Sigma^m$. Now both $x$ and $y$ are vertices of the cube $\Sigma^m$.

Now isn't $\text{ed}(x,y)$ the shortest distance between $x$ and $y$ in this cube graph? Why isn't edit distance found by finding shortest paths in this cube?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the two strings 01010101 and 10101010. They have distance 8 on the cube but their edit distance is 2.

Comment: Why is the edit distance 2 here?

Comment: Because you allow insertions and deletions.

Comment: Oh okay - I understand - you want to insert a 1 at the beginning and delete the last 1.

Comment: So is there any mathematical notion of distance which corresponds to this notion of "edit distance" ?

Comment: That is a new question... or a different version of your question.

Comment: Yeah..I am trying to understand if anything in usual mathematics corresponds to this notion of edit distance.

Comment: Try small examples. See if there is some regularity.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23872/discussion-between-andre-souza-lemos-and-user6818).

Comment: @user6818 Edit distance is a rather arbitrary concept. Why these three transformations, and no other? Then the substitution is not even needed, since anything can be done with insertion/deletion. What kind of mathematical concept are you looking for?

Comment: @babou Substitutions are more efficient that insertion + deletion. It affects the cost function.

Comment: That may depend on the string representation regarding effective
cost. Regarding the distance itself, more primitive editing operations
could reduce it further. But my point was more about finding abstract
underlying mathematical structures, as the OP is trying to. I would
think that using a minimal system might be better to evidence one, if
any is to be found. From that point of view, the chosen set of editing
primitives is somewhat arbitrary.